# Pods not updating after expoKit updates to 33

Tags: cocoapods, expo

When i type pod update in expoKit ios folder i get an error.  I found this link
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2148#issuecomment-416597679

So I deleted the offending modules and rebuilt.  However I got another issue that

No podspec found for `EXCameraInterface` in `../node_modules/expo-file-system-interface/ios

I checked my node modules and indeed it was not there.  I tried deleting and reinstalling node modules to no success.  I then deleted EXCameraInterface and got the same issue with the next library and then the next etc.

Edit: My cocopods version is 1.7.2, tried degrading to 1.5.3 but it never helped.

Comment: Have you downgraded the cocoa pod?

Comment: which version should I downgrade too?  I am currently on 1.7.2.

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2148#issuecomment-416615608

Comment: Please downgrade to 1.5.3

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: Have you done everything to this link?  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/#upgrading-expokit

Comment: the very first action is to update node modules, update expokit to "ios/2.11.1e" and then pod update

Comment: Did you do this? Open ios/your-project/Supporting/EXSDKVersions.plist in your project and change all the values to the new SDK version.

Comment: yeh ive done that - although i dont see how it would effect finding data in my node modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer

"
Remove the list of unimodules' dependencies:
  pod 'EXAdsAdMob',
    :path => "../node_modules/expo-ads-admob/ios"
  pod 'EXSegment',
    :path => "../node_modules/expo-analytics-segment/ios"
  pod 'EXAppAuth',
    :path => "../node_modules/expo-app-auth/ios"
  # and so on...
and instead add:
  # Install unimodules
  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
  use_unimodules!
"

It appears I cant read

Comment: Doesn't help that it's only after they tell you to run `pod update` that they tell you what you have to do to get it to work (https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/expokit/expokit/#upgrading-expokit)